# android using setlistadapter() without extending listactivity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

lots of searching and reading has not provided the answer to this problem.
my activity does not extend ListActivity so this line throws an error.
setListAdapter(fileList);

it is supposed to populate a listview, any solid help is much appreciated.

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
    setListAdapter(fileList);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Obtain the reference of your `ListView` using `findViewById(int)`. Then call the method `ListView.setAdapter(ListAdapter)` on that reference with your adapter as the parameter.