# how to correctly call setListAdapter

Tags: android

I've searched how to solve this problem a lot, but i did not get any result. the only help that i need is, please take a look at this question asked on stackoverflow and on answer;

here is the question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063757/android-using-setlistadapter-without-extending-listactivity) link:

"my activity does not extend ListActivity so this line throws an error. setListAdapter(fileList); it is supposed to populate a listview..."

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
setListAdapter(fileList);
```

the answer to this question is:

Obtain the reference of your `ListView` using `findViewById(int)`. Then call the method `ListView.setAdapter(ListAdapter)` on that reference with your adapter as the parameter.

now here is my code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
     new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.reminder_row, R.id.text1, items);

    setListAdapter(adapter); 

}
```

considering the Q/A, could someone please explain how exactly do i write it in the correct way. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I get an error on setListAdapter

The method setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>) is undefined for the type ReminderListActivity

Comment: i am recommended to create method setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<string>)
i did, and the program does not work as it is supposed. how do i correctly fix this error?

Comment: From what I'm seeing I feel that you need to make an implementation of the `setListAdapter` method or you maybe u should be using the method implemented in the base class...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063757/android-using-setlistadapter-without-extending-listactivity 

I have the exact issue as here. But i am beginner, and i do not know how to do that. could anyone please explain what should i do?

Comment: Like explained in the example get your ListView:

    `ListView myListView = findViewById(int);`
    `myListView.setListAdapter(adapter);`
Can you try this out if it works as expected...

Comment: the application crashes. i added the code in the question. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Can u post ur full class code here..?

Comment: @LuchFilip I'm confused as to what you're referring to. You have no setListAdapter in your code?

Comment: i posted the updated code from what @NREZ said, but now i updated the code, please take a look and write it in correct way, i am sure its matter of 1-2 lines. Thank you in advance.

Comment: LuchFilip did you find your solution..? I think @laalto has given a good answer, please try it out...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As explained in the linked question and in this question's comments, it goes like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.reminder_row, R.id.text1, items);
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.your_listview_id);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`ListActivity` is a specialized `Activity` that hosts a `ListView` and has some convenience methods for accessing and manipulating it. However, nothing prevents you from having a `ListView` in a non-`ListActivity` `Activity`, you just lose the convenience methods and will have to write some more code yourself, like above.

Answer (score 2):

[laalto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/101361/laalto) is right, but you can also just extend ListActivity in your current activity.

```
public class YourListActivityClass extends ListActivity {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.reminder_row, R.id.text1, items);
        setListAdapter(adapter); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

we can do listview in AppCompatActivity

```
String[] one = {"dsk", "jskj", "ddd", "dld"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_row, R.id.list_row_name, one);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

setListAdapter is undefined because ReminderListActivity doesn't extend ListActivity. So to solve this you need to extend ListActivity.