# How to use setAdapter without extending ListActivity

Tags: android, listadapter

I have to populate a custom list-view. 
This list view contains a textbox.

Listview XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listsong2_screen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/panel_shape" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back_btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Back_Recent_Song" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listsong_recent_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white" >
</ListView>
```

This is custom list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:padding="5dp">
  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/songTitlerecent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:color="#f3f3f3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Main XML file :

```
       <include android:id="@+id/list_song_layout2"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       layout="@layout/list_recentsongs_screen" />
```

How to use setlistadapter without extending listactivity ?

Code :

```
            ListView recent =  (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listsong_recent_listview);
      ArrayList<Data> List = new ArrayList<Data>();
    //Populate the array list
     Log.d("Debug1*****************","******************");

     List.add(new Data("test album1")); // Set Name
     List.add(new Data("test album2"));
     List.add(new Data("test album3"));


     for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            Data dataobj = List.get(i);

            String Name = dataobj.getName();
            Log.d("Debug" ,"Name = "  +  Name);


     }
     //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
     Log.d("Debug2*****************","******************");
     Integer size = List.size();

     Log.d("Debug3*****************","******************");
     Log.d("DEBUG123","size of list "+ size);

     Log.d("Debug4*****************","******************");
     m_adapter = new MetadataArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.recentlistsong_item,   List);   // MetadataArrayAdapter is a class extending ArrayAdapter<Data> 

     // Data is a pojo class 

     recent.findViewById(R.id.listsong_recent_listview);

     Log.d("Debug7*****************","******************");
     recent.setAdapter(m_adapter);
```

MetaAdapter Class :

```
public class MetadataArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MusicMetadata> {

// declaring our ArrayList of items
private ArrayList<MusicMetadata> objects;

/* here we must override the constructor for ArrayAdapter
* the only variable we care about now is ArrayList<PojoClass> objects,
* because it is the list of objects we want to display.
*/
public MetadataArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<MusicMetadata> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.objects = objects;
}

/*
 * we are overriding the getView method here - this is what defines how each
 * list item will look.
 */
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    // assign the view we are converting to a local variable
    View v = convertView;

    // first check to see if the view is null. if so, we have to inflate it.
    // to inflate it basically means to render, or show, the view.
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listsong_item, null);
    }

    /*
     * Recall that the variable position is sent in as an argument to this method.
     * The variable simply refers to the position of the current object in the list. (The ArrayAdapter
     * iterates through the list we sent it)
     * 
     * Therefore, i refers to the current Item object.
     */
    MusicMetadata i = objects.get(position);

    if (i != null) {

        // This is how you obtain a reference to the TextViews.
        // These TextViews are created in the XML files we defined.

        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.songTitlerecent);


        // check to see if each individual textview is null.
        // if not, assign some text!
        if (tt != null){
            tt.setText("Title :" + i.getAlbum());
        }

    }

    // the view must be returned to our activity
    return v;
}
```

}

I am not able to see the list. What else I have to add here?

With reference to Link : [android using setlistadapter() without extending listactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063757/android-using-setlistadapter-without-extending-listactivity)

How to use setAdapter without extending list activity ?

Please let me know what is wrong ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: listView.setAdapter(<your adapter>);

Comment: post your adapter code `MetadataArrayAdapter`

Comment: I have posted the metadataarrayAdapter

Comment: @Jeet i made few modifications and i used a ViewHolder pattern. check my eidt

Comment: @Jeet what is `Data` class and `MusicMetadata`?.

Comment: @Jeet do you have a class by name `MusicMetadata` if so can you post the same and also `Data` class

Comment: its the same Data = MusicData Class

Comment: how can it be same. they are two different classes right? BTW why would you have the two different classes if you have the same content.Any way use the code in my post it will work

Comment: @Jeet also your list is populated using Data. So can you post both the classes to avoid confusion

Comment: I changed the code before posting it here, There is No Data class, its MusicData class only. And with my code the error was silly, I was populating another adapter and loading it on the listview. Thanks for help @Raghunandan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intialize the listview and use setAdapter to set the adapter to listview

```
 m_adapter = new MetadataArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.recentlistsong_item, RecentSongsList);  
 ListView recent =  (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listsong_recent_listview);
 recent.setAdapter(m_adapter);
```

Remove this `recent.findViewById(R.id.listsong_recent_listview)`

> I am not able to see the list. What else I have to add here?

Check your adapter code and see the code in `getView`

Edit:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    MetadataArrayAdapter m_adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        ListView recent =  (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
        ArrayList<Data> List = new ArrayList<Data>();
       List.add(new Data("test album1")); // Set Name
       List.add(new Data("test album2"));
       List.add(new Data("test album3"));
       m_adapter = new MetadataArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_song_item,   List);  
       recent.setAdapter(m_adapter);
    }
  }
```

Data.java

```
public class Data {
String name;
public Data(String name)
{
    this.name= name;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

MetadatArrayAdapter

```
public class MetadataArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data> {

    private ArrayList<Data> objects;
     LayoutInflater inflater ;
    public MetadataArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Data> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        ViewHolder holder; 
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_song_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.songTitlerecent);
            convertView.setTag(holder); 
        } else { 
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
        } 

        Data i = objects.get(position);
        if (i != null) {
         holder.tv.setText(i.getName());

        }
        return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView tv;
    }
    }
```

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listsong2_screen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back_btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Back_Recent_Song" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

list_song_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:padding="5dp">
  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/songTitlerecent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:color="#f3f3f3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148618/listview-not-refreshing-after-click-on-button