# How to list directories or files in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to create an Android app that can select file/s in Android phone and upload it to a server. When I click "upload" button, I want my app to display all the files and folders stored in the phone, so user can select the files to upload. I want to display it like in the Dropbox app. In Dropbox app, when user click "Upload here"->"Other Files", it will show the files and folders in Android internal storage (or external storage??Not sure about this). I wish I could show the screenshot, but I don't have enough reputation to post image.

This is what I've done so far, but it doesn't show similar result.

```
private void getDir(String dirPath){
    pathTitle.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();

    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    if(!dirPath.equals(root)){
        item.add(root);
        path.add(root);

        item.add("../");
        path.add(f.getParent());
    }

    //File[] files = f.listFiles();
    if(files != null){
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            File file = files[i];
            path.add(file.getPath());
            if(file.isDirectory()){
                item.add(file.getName() + "/");
            }
            else{
                item.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
    setListAdapter(fileList);
}
```

Could anyone guide me through this? I am still newbie in Android app development.

Thanks

Comment: Please upload the screenshot to Imgur and post the link here, and someone will fix it up. Furthermore, please describe what exactly "it doesn't show similar result" means. Do you get nothing, only some files, a crash, or what? Does [this answer help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063757/android-using-setlistadapter-without-extending-listactivity)?

Comment: Ok, here is the link: http://i.imgur.com/uCL9LYt.png. What I mean is I don't get similar result as the pictures. Thx

Comment: Sorry, that still doesn't help me - what does _your_ program look like or do?

Comment: Right now, Im still trying to create simple File Explorer or Browser for my app. I just want to know the right way to do it.Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm suggesting you to use Simple file chooser - https://github.com/ingyesid/simple-file-chooser library. Here you can select file and have it's path onActivityResult. Then you can start uploading task.

If you want, you can check source code of the library.